# Indexing XML (DITA) files with Lucene and Querying on Attribute values

Tags: xml, lucene, aem, dita

We are trying to implement complex indexing for XML (DITA) files in AEM using Lucene. Right now, searches are supported by the full-text index.

For example: 
In the below document, all text is extracted and indexed to facilitate full-text queries on the document content.

```
<concept id="lawnmowerconcept" xml:lang="en-us">
<title>Lawnmower</title>
<conbody product="mower25h">
    <p>The lawnmower is a machine used to cut grass in the yard. Lawnmowers can be electric, gas-powered, or manual.</p>
</conbody>
</concept>
```

Now, the ask is to also allow specialized XML searches. For example:

- A user can search by an element name. e.g. el:conbody - This should only return documents that have the `<conbody>` element.
- A user can search by an attribute name. E.g. @product=”%” – This should only return documents that have the product attribute applied to at least one of its element. Note we’re not concerned about the value of this attribute.
- A user can search by an attribute name-value pair. E.g. @product=”mower25h” – This should only return documents that have the product attribute applied to at least one of its element with the value mower25h.

What would be the best way to go about implementing:

- Continue using the full-text index but use a custom Lucene Analyzer to preserve the XML markup. E.g. `<title>Lawnmower</title>` would be broken down into `<title>,  Lawnmower,  </title>` without stripping the special chars.
- Create a new full-text index with a custom analyzer that strips all text content and only indexes the element, attribute names and attribute values. Would it be possible to have an intersection of two indexes?
  For e.g. a query like el:p=%lawnmower% would return the above document because it has a `<p>` element with lawnmower text.
- Or should I completely avoid AEM Lucene and preferably go for an external index like Solr?

Comment: AEM is a web CMS that displays HTML files, are you displaying raw DITA XML files with AEM? Or are you using the AEM plugin for XML/DITA documentation? And it only has a full text search capability?